# How to call sql loader through stored procedure?

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, sql-loader

I'm trying to call sql loader through stored procedure but I'm not able to use the result, Is there any way to call sql loader through stored procedure or I will use  shell script to call the stored procedure.

Comment: Why do you want to do this from a SP?  What are you trying to accomplish?  sqlldr is a command-line exe.  You could possibly use dbms_scheduler to execute an external program.

Comment: Is this question now redundant, since you [seem to have switched to using external tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32113977/266304)? If so this can be closed, or you can delete it, perhaps.