# PLS-00103 creating an external table with dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to dynamically create an external table but I'm getting error message `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXTERNAL"`. I'm also using `ora_hash` in the external table definition; please let me know it is the right way to get the `ora_hash` value.

```
create or replace procedure CHECKTABLEEXIST1 (p_tab_name in varchar2,DATAFILE in varchar2) --user_tables.table_name%type)                                    
is                                     
tab_name varchar2(100) := p_tab_name;                                    
n Number(3);                                    
ext_table varchar(100) := tab_name|| ' as select * from xyz WHERE 1=0';                                    
begin                                    
select  count(*) into n from tab where TName=upper(tab_name);                                    

--dbms_output.put_line(n);                                    

if n=0 then                                    
execute immediate 'create table ' || ext_table ;                                    
else                                    
execute immediate 'drop table ' || tab_name;                                    
execute immediate 'create table ' || ext_table;                                    
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
(
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY DE_DUBFILE
ACCESS PARAMETER 
    (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    CHARACTERSET US7ASCII
    BADFILE     'UPLOAD':'p_tab_name.bad'
    DISCARDFILE 'UPLOAD':'p_tab_name.dis'
    LOGFILE     'UPLOAD':'p_tab_name.log'
    FILEDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    TRAILING NULLCOLS 
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
    t1 ,t2,t3,t4,t5 date "YYYYMMDD" ,t6,t7,
    t8 ,t9 ,
    DETL_CLMNS_HASH "ORA_HASH( :t4||:t7 )",
    KEY_CLMNS_HASH "ORA_HASH(:t1||:t2||:t5)", t10,t11)
    )

LOCATION (DATAFILE)    

);
end if;

end;
```

I'm getting error message :

```
LINE/COL ERROR                                                            
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
16/14    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXTERNAL" when expecting one o
         f the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything from `ORGANIZATION` onwards is being seen as PL/SQL code, not part of your dynamic SQL statement. You're appending the table name to the `create table` but then not appending the rest as part of that statement string. You need to do something like:

```
execute immediate 'create table ' || p_tab_name || '
( /* put column names and types here */ )                  
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
(
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY DE_DUBFILE
ACCESS PARAMETERS 
    (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    CHARACTERSET US7ASCII
    BADFILE     UPLOAD:''' || p_tab_name || '.bad''
    DISCARDFILE UPLOAD:''' || p_tab_name || '.dis''
    LOGFILE     UPLOAD:''' || p_tab_name || '.log''
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','' 
    optionally enclosed by ''"''
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
    t1 ,t2,t3,t4,t5 date mask "YYYYMMDD" ,t6,t7,
    t8 ,t9, t10,t11
    )    
LOCATION (''' || DATAFILE || ''')    
)';
```

In the first line the terminating semicolon has been replaced with concatenation of a new string literal. The references to variables `p_tab_name` and `DATAFILE` have to be broken out from that literal too, requiring more single quotes and concatenation; and the single quotes that are actually part of the statement need to be escaped by doubling them up. There were various other quotes missing as well. What's shown should now run.

I've also change the table name being used to just `p_tab_name`, but you need to specify the column names and data types explicitly. It doesn't make sense to use `as select * ...` for an external table. That isn't legal syntax, either before `organization` or after the rest if the current statement. I suppose you could extract that information from `all_tab_columns` and build that part dynamically too, but if you're basing it on a fixed table you ought to know those anyway.

Your logic for dropping/creating is off too - I think you just want:

```
if n>0 then                                    
  execute immediate 'drop table ' || p_tab_name; 
end if;
execute immediate 'create table ' || p_tab_name || '
...
```

... so you don't have to repeat the create statement in both branches.

---

I've also corrected a couple of other mistakes; `PARAMETERS` rather then `PARAMETER`; `FIELDS` rather then `FILEDS`; removed `TRAILING NULLCOLS`. Try to execite the command as static SQL before converting it to dynamic. There may still be other issues.

And I've removed the last two calculated columns:

```
    DETL_CLMNS_HASH "ORA_HASH( :t4||:t7 )",
    KEY_CLMNS_HASH "ORA_HASH(:t1||:t2||:t5)")
```

The [`ORACLE_LOADER` driver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1420) doesn't allow manipulations like that; SQL*Loader does but they are not exactly the same. You also can't define virtual columns on an external table. If you're using this as a staging table to load data into another (real) table then you can calculate those hashes during the transfer; otherwise you can create a view over this external table which includes the calculated columns.

Comment: Alex thanks for your reply basically I'm trying to copy the data structure of xyz table into dynamic table that way I'm using .I have one more question I'm not able load the date into dynamic table but I'm able to copy the data structure of xyz table.

Comment: @akhileshchand - I see; but you can't do that. I'd suggest you get the creation statement working as static SQL before trying to convert it to dynamic; you have a few other mistakes in there at the moment.

Comment: Alex, I'm getting below error ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "double-quoted-string": expecting one of: "binary_double, binary_float, comma, char, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, no, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"
KUP-01007: at line 13 column 80

Script Terminated on line 6.

Comment: @akhileshchand - updated to note that the external table driver doesn't allow everything that SQL\*Loader does.